# fusiontable query for where

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-fusion-tables

Is there any way to generate where condition based on user input dynamically.I have a select box with the option '>','<','equals','starts with','ends with'.Based on this condition where clause should be generated and query should be executed.Please help me.i need examples.
since i have around 80 columns in my table i cant use if else loop.

```
function querymap()


{
var querypass=document.getElementById('query-pass').value.replace(/'/g, "\\'");
 if(querypass=='hhSanitHouseType')
   {
     var operator=document.getElementById('operatorstring').value.replace(/'/g, "\\'");
     if(operator=='>')
        { 
          var textvalue=document.getElementById("text-value").value.replace(/'/g, "\\'");
          layer.setQuery("SELECT 'geometry',hhSanitHouseType FROM " + tableid + " WHERE 'hhSanitHouseType' > '" + textvalue + "'");


        }
     }
   else
   {
   alert("false");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can [check this example](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/samples/dynamic_styling_template), especially the function `generateWhere(columnName, low, high)`.

You don't have to use if/else for your operator, just check for a valid input (i.e. that the operator is one of  '>','<','equals','starts with','ends with') and then pass it directly to your query, something like that

```
 var operator = ...;
 var textvalue = ...;
 layer.setQuery("SELECT 'geometry',hhSanitHouseType FROM " + tableid + " WHERE 'hhSanitHouseType'" + operator + " '" + textvalue + "'");
```

Comment: If suppose i have three var such as 'columnname','operator','textvalue'.Is it possible to get columnname as variable and pass it to query.please tel me how to do this.

Comment: i dont want to specify that hhSanitHouseType also in the query.It should also be directly obtained from one more variable called 'columnname'.

Comment: @user1225902 Yes of course it's like the other variables, just obtain the value from the form with something like `var columnname=document.getElementById("columnname").value` and then use it in your query: `layer.setQuery("SELECT 'geometry'," + columnname + " FROM " + tableid + " WHERE " + columnname + " " + operator + " '" + textvalue + "'");`

Comment: thank you...i was expecting this only..i got it...this suits perfect for my code...

Comment: With this I have to add 'and' condition.

Comment: var villageName=document.getElementById("villagename").value;            var columnname=document.getElementById("columnname").value; layer.setQuery("SELECT 'geometry'," + columnname + " FROM " + tableid + " WHERE " + columnname + " " + operator + " '" + textvalue + "'" + "and"+VillageName='madurai');Is This is a correct code